# Problems with htaccess directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

So, I have this .htaccess code (that I don't know if it's the best way to write it):

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1&$2= [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1&$2=$3 [L]
```

And at index.php I have this code to load the content:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <?
        $p = ($_GET['p'] ? $_GET['p'] : 'home');
        include_once('lib/'.$p.'.php')
    ?>
</div>
```

When I access `www.web.com/home`, for example, it works fine loading all files; BUT when I access `www.web.com/articles/read/asd`, all the other files, instead of loading like `www.web.com/lib/pixel.png`, they load like `www.web.com/articles/lib/pixel.png`.

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Does your site live? if so just post your site URL. So one can check and revert back to you

Comment: It's on localhost :/

Comment: Actually your code is good. and I don't think that you have to face such an issue. Can you please be more clear with your question? Are you accessing the image directly or there is any link to do so? and more ..

Comment: Use `src="/lib/pixel.png"` in your HTML. Or set `<base href="/">` in the `<head>`.

Comment: I'm accessing all the other files like `'lib/blabla.css'`, like in `<img src="lib/pixel.png">`

Comment: The point is that you need the leading slash so that the request is made relative to the domain root.

Comment: but if my website is in another folder, like `www.web.com/v2/lib/pixel.png`, using a slash would access like `www.web.com/lib/pixel.png`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, so use the correct path in your `src` or set the base `href` to `/v2/`.

Comment: And, for a bit of learning, you can change your `.htaccess` to [this](https://gist.github.com/mikerockett/2d62581c1ad1c69ab632). No need to repeat the file/directory check.

Comment: Pls show your code where (how) you call `pixel.png`

Comment: I've solved it, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved my problem: I made this code:

```
$p = ($_GET['p'] ? $_GET['p'] : 'home');

$directory_folder = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$directory_folder = $directory_folder[1];
$directory_folder = ($directory_folder == $p ? '' : $directory_folder);
```

So, if I'm accessing through `www.web.com/` or `www.web.com/test`, it would return the directory of my website that I want. I just had to add the `/<? echo $directory_folder ?>/` to all my src's and href's, but it was worth it.

Thanks to  Mike Rockett and all the guys helping me :)